# Static Equilibrium: cable sag considering equal pulling forces on extremities

Tags: forces, mass, torque

When considering a cable with a non-negligible mass and an equal force pulling the cable at both extremities, how can one compute the mid-span sag or a sag function whilst accounting for this pulling force ?

Comment: Can you provide a diagram? It sounds like you're asking about the [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) equations, but I can't be sure.